# awk split returns index

Tags: awk, split

I want to obtain an array named ids, containing all those values from a string passed as a variable:

```
426
425
422
415
405
397
349
310
254
167
0
```

I found this code should work:

```
awk -v branches="426;425;422;415;405;397;349;310;254;167;0" 'BEGIN { split( branches, ids, ";" ); for (id in ids){print id}}'
```

However it gives me:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

And if I take it out from the BEGIN block, it just stops there and outputs nothing...

Comment: **typo alert** : var `i` != `id`. and you probably reall want `print ids[id]`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: @shellter And you were right, it works when called this way (ids[id]). But I don't understand, since it works well in another script: `awk -v rt_id=$rt_id1 -v cell_area=$cell_area 'BEGIN {RS=" ";}  NR==FNR { ids[$1]; next } NR!=FNR { RS="\n"; if ($3 == rt_id) { for (id in ids) if( $4 == id ) {print $2*cell_area, $1, $3, $4}}}' longest_branch1.txt $kcnfile`

Comment: values are the values in the array, not the index, `id` is the index of the array.

Comment: wrt `NR!=FNR { RS="\n";` in the script in your comment - that is setting `RS` **after** `RS` has already been used so it won't work. You should do `awk 'script' RS=' ' file1 RS='\n' file2` to use a different RS in each file.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the values to be the keys to the array, you need to do one more step.

```
$ awk -v branches="426;425;422;415;405;397;349;310;254;167;0" '
        BEGIN {n=split(branches,idV,";"); 
               for(i=1;i<=n;i++) ids[idV[i]]; 
               for(id in ids) print id}'

0
167
254
310
349
397
405
415
422
425
426
```

note that the values will not be in the same insertion order.  This can be called more like a hash set, rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perl version:

```sh
echo "426;425;422;415;405;397;349;310;254;167;0" | perl -ne ' chomp;print(join("\n",sort(split(/;/))))'
0
167
254
310
349
397
405
415
422
425
```

chomp - removes the newline.